# batch file permutation to output to textfile results

Tags: algorithm, batch-file

i want a simple batch file that will display the permutations to a text file, after asking the user to input the following:

How many numbers for Permutation?: example say 6
----clear screen-----

Enter 1st number for Permutation:
Enter range: example 1-32          (Note the "-" is the delimiter used for spaces)
----clear screen-----

Enter 2nd number for Permutation:
Enter range: example 3-24          (Note the "-" is the delimiter used for spaces)
----clear screen-----

Enter 3rd number for Permutation:
Enter range: example 2-16          (Note the "-" is the delimiter used for spaces)
----clear screen-----

And so on..........

note: the textfile permutation results should be delimited like 5-25-6-15-22-8

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i'm asking the experts how can my requirements be coded in a Batch format. i know very little about batch files and coding in general. trying to learn here. i'm eagerly anticipating your coded answer to this be question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $Liste=
set /p "$PNumber=Number of permutation ? : " 
for /l %%a in (1,1,%$Pnumber%) do (
  set /p "$Value=Enter Permutation Number [ %%a ] : "
  set $Liste=!$Liste!-!$Value!)
echo !$Liste:~1!>output.txt
```

Comment: i noticed that your batch file doesn't create any Permutations, and also it doesn't ask the user after each number entered to state the range he wants like 1-29. the range would be like a "For a=1 to 29". i know how to do this in VBA but not sure how its done in batch coding

Comment: What do you mean with PERMUTATION ? A random number ?

Comment: for example...if by the code you have above i input 1-2-3-4-5-6, the permutation would give me all the possible ways in which it can be ordered like 1-2-3-4-5-6, 2-1-3-4-5-6, 3-1-2-4-5-6, 4-1-2-3-5-6, and so on..continue to the end. i want "each" number i input to have a range like the 1st number range from 1-25, the second number range from 3-21 and so on. The user should be asked the range for each number.